# Why doesn't MySQL optimizer do index merge from indexes in two different tables?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index, optimization, mysql-8.0

***Query1*** takes almost 2000x more time than ***Query2***.

The criteria is of form
`tbl1.key1 = x or tbl2.key1 = y`

***Query 1***

```sql
SELECT 
    `t1`.`t1_PK`
FROM
    `t1`
        JOIN
    `rel_t1_t2` ON `t1`.`t1_PK` = `rel_t1_t2`.`t1_PK`
        JOIN
    `t2` ON `rel_t1_t2`.`t2_PK` = `t2`.`t2_PK`
        JOIN
    `rel_t1_t3` ON `t1`.`t1_PK` = `rel_t1_t3`.`t1_PK`
        JOIN
    `t3` ON `rel_t1_t3`.`t3_PK` = `t3`.`t3_PK`
WHERE
    ((`t2`.`keycol2` = 2292268)
        OR (`t3`.`keycol3` = 3369384));
```

***Plan 1***

[image]

***Query 2***

```sql
SELECT 
    `t1`.`t1_PK`
FROM
    `t1`
        JOIN
    `rel_t1_t2` ON `t1`.`t1_PK` = `rel_t1_t2`.`t1_PK`
        JOIN
    `t2` ON `rel_t1_t2`.`t2_PK` = `t2`.`t2_PK`
WHERE
    ((`t2`.`keycol2` = 2292268)) 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    `t1`.`t1_PK`
FROM
    `t1`
        JOIN
    `rel_t1_t3` ON `t1`.`t1_PK` = `rel_t1_t3`.`t1_PK`
        JOIN
    `t3` ON `rel_t1_t3`.`t3_PK` = `t3`.`t3_PK`
WHERE
    (`t3`.`keycol3` = 3369384);
```

***Plan 2***
[image]

This [Index Merge Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html) that happens for different keys in same table, is not happening for indexes from multiple tables. Why hasn't MySQL optimizer taken care of this case also?

Comment: that is something that only oracle can answer

Answer (score 0):

Index "merge" can only be applied if you have ids (or row numbers or whatever) from a single table.

Your Query 2 essentially does that.  If you need more columns than just `t1_PK`, then consider

```
SELECT t1.*
    FROM ((Query 2)) AS x
    JOIN t1 USING(t1_PK);
```